# Posting Image and Text with angular, express and multer

Tags: node.js, angular, express, form-data

I am self-learning angular and feel struggling when trying to post images and text to the server. The backend work as intened when tested with postman but fail when working with angular. Here is the code I used:

upload.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="uploadForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="description">Trip Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="description" class="form-control" formControlName="text" placeholder="description">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="image">Cover Image</label>
    <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control-file" id="image">
  </div>

  <input type='submit' value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

upload.component.ts

```
private preSubmit(): any {
  let input = new FormData();
  input.append('description', this.uploadForm.get('description').value);
  input.append('image', this.uploadForm.get('image').value);
  return input;
}

onSubmit() {
const newImage = this.preSubmit();
this.http.post('apiUrl', newImage)
}
```

NodeJS

```
router.post('/', multer().single('image'), async (req, res) => {
const upload = {
    imgID: uuidv4(),
    description: req.body.description,
    image: req.file.originalname,
};
postparams = { Key: upload.imgID, Body: req.file.buffer };
await s3Bucket.putObject(postparams, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error uploading Image: ', err);
    } else {
        console.log('Image uploaded: ', upload.imgID);
    }
});
knex('image')
    .insert(image).then(images => {
        res.json(images)
    });
});
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to upload?

Comment: it showed "cannot read property of null" on console

Comment: What cannot read property of null?

Comment: UploadComponent.html:10 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at UploadComponent.preSubmit (upload.component.ts:78)
    at UploadComponent.onSubmit (upload.component.ts:83)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (UploadComponent.html:10)
    at handleEvent (core.js:13547)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15056)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:14643)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:9962)
    at eval (core.js:12301)
    at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js:4343)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:243)

Comment: above is the error message i received

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert but try this.

```
uploadForm: FormGroup;

private preSubmit(): any {
  let input = new FormData();
  input.append('description', this.uploadForm.value.description);
  input.append('image', this.uploadForm.value.image);
  return input;
}
```

Or this

```
private preSubmit(): any {
  return this.uploadForm = new FormGroup ({
    description: new FormControl(),
    image: new FormControl()   }) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the multer doc: **Multer will not process any form which is not multipart (multipart/form-data).**

Therefore, you need to add the following to your form :

enctype="multipart/form-data"